# Is there any added advantage to getting Presidential Postdoctoral fellowship (STEM) over regular postdoc appointment?

Tags: united-states, postdocs, stem

Is it more prestigious? Does it help to have it on your resume, if you are applying for faculty positions later on? How does a presidential fellowship compare to a regular postdoc appointment at a prestigious university? General pros and cons? What makes a good postdoc offer in terms of professional growth? I am about to defend soon and need to make a decision. Thank you.

This fellowship is based in the US, applicants submit a research proposal along with their choice of mentor or PI. Then the fellows are chosen from that pool. Similar to https://ppfp.ucop.edu/info/. In particular, I am in Electrical Engineering, working on signal processing and communication.

Comment: I think you need to tell us which country these are in, and what specifically these Presidential Postdoctoral Fellowships are/how one gets those.

Comment: Is [this](https://ppfp.ucop.edu/info/) the fellowship you’re referring to?

Comment: This is in the US, applicants submit a research proposal along with their choice of mentor or PI. Then the fellows are chosen from that pool.

Comment: Dan Romik, yes same idea but different university not in the UC group.

Comment: Well, okay, but the answer could depend quite a lot on which fellowship exactly this is, so don’t expect a high quality answer if you won’t provide that detail.

Comment: Any answer would be better than no answer, and greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I think knowing what field you are in would also help, as different fields have different cultures (and different levels of competitiveness for faculty position).

Comment: Thanks I am in Electrical Engineering, signal processing and communication in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about this particular fellowship, and you'd like to not mention a specific one, which I think is fine - this site does not want to get into recommendations for specific graduate programs, journals, etc, and I think this falls into that category.

I will give a more general answer regarding postdoctoral funding:

**It is an asset in future job applications to show that you are able to generate funding for your research.**

A competitive fellowship application based on the merits of a research proposal you have submitted would be included in that. If it's just a fancy label assigned to your work under some PI, it probably isn't.

A fellowship that people are familiar with likely counts better than one no one outside a given institution would know: if they know how hard it is to get, say, a postdoctoral fellowship from NSF, then they know the value of having that on your resume. If it's some lesser known fellowship, it'll be up to you to make the case that it's important.

Just like applicants for graduate school, applicants for academic jobs will be evaluated on a broad basis. No one factor will get you or cost you a job, so you'll need to weigh funding sources versus all the other aspects of a post doc that will influence your success in publishing papers, etc.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate your answer and its very helpful

Comment: I'd also comment that, just from my anecdotal experience, prestige of a postdoc and its desirability in terms of "typical" employment factors (length, pay, etc.) are often closely correlated, though not always.

Comment: + 1. I would also add that something to look at is that NSF and similar post docs often do not have benefits whereas a plain post doc through a profs funding does. Something for the OP to consider is what benefits they are trading. Also, begin _Dr. Smith's_ post doc might be better than an NSF post doc with a lower _Dr. not famous_ if Dr. Smith's network helps her post docs get _better_ (in the eye of the bolder) jobs as the next step.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly why asked this question.